# why no pixels are bieng plotted using pixel manipulation.

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to display pixels at x and y using create/putimagedata but no pixels are being printed anyone know why this is?

http://jsfiddle.net/8kg6yvnw/

```
function setPixel(imageData, x, y, r, g, b, a)
```

Comment: Just like for your other post, you should go step by step to build your solution : Have first a most basic app working, then add features. Here : test that you do draw points before going further. Because even this very simplified version contains two errors : http://jsfiddle.net/8kg6yvnw/15/  (hints : one bug is the html, the other is almost at the end of the code).